# Insert Text containg Reserved Word?

Tags: php, mysql

I'm attempting to update a column with a string that contains a reserved word.

```
$val1 = "Boat's Devices"; // inserts fine
$val2 = "Boat's Float"; // fails
```

Error:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 's Float'

```
mysql_query("UPDATE phrases SET head_title = '$val1', title = '$val2' WHERE p_id = '$p_id'") or die(mysql_error());
```

Comment: Can you show us your SQL statement? I have a feeling the problem lies there...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to escape all strings that you insert into a MySQL database. Use mysql_real_escape_string or an equivalent to do so. This should resolve your problem. If not, please post your SQL query so that we can take a look at it.

Comment: I tried using mysql_real_escape_string and the 's Float error went away but another one popped up for reasons that aren't clear.

Comment: It would be helpful if you could post the exact error message that you received this time.

Comment: Well, it seems I need the ''s around my variable for it to insert properly. When I use mysql_real_escape_string('$val2'), it says FUNCTION database2.mysql_real_escape_string does not exist. If I remove the ''s, it gives me the same error as if I tried to just insert the value as $val2 instead of '$val2'

Comment: if i do 'mysql_real_escape_string($val2)' it gives me the same error about 's Float as above.

Comment: mysql_real_escape_string is a PHP function, not a MYSQL function. So you would apply it on PHP level. E.g. $var1 = mysql_real_escape_string("Boat's Devices");

Comment: There are a bunch of things at play here.  Your values contain single quotes which MySQL is interpreting as the end of string character.  When in doubt, especially with SQL, put echo statements everywhere to see where things go wrong.  In your case the SQL looks like this:

    mysql_query("UPDATE phrases SET head_title = 'Boat's Device', title = 'Boat's Float' WHERE p_id = '123'") or die(mysql_error());

Comment: MySQL cannot parse out which single quote ends the string so you need to escape it using mysql_real_escape_string as above.  When you call this function there is no need to put `$val2` in quotes.  It is a PHP rule that variables in single quotes are not interpolated (replaced) and those in double quotes are.  So you could use `mysql_real_escape_string("$val2")` but you should just use `mysql_real_escape_string($val2)`.  The difference is the same as why you would do `addToCart($x)` not `addToCart($x*1)` or `addToCart($x+0)`.